# How to pass data to child view controller before invocation of parent controller's viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, core-data, storyboard, uicontainerview

I need to display user data in container view when my app start running.

I routinely read data with Core Data inside parent view controller's `viewDidLoad` method. And I tried to send data to the child view controller with the `prepareForSegue` method through a embed segue. But as I find out, the `prepareForSegue` is called before the `viewDidLoad` method. That means, `prepareForSegue` has no valid data to send to child view controller.

What can I do with it?

Comment: A little more information would assist. For example... Where and when do you instantiate your Core Data stack? Have you considered the TVC lifecycle method `loadView`? What objects are you retrieving for each TVC and are you using an `NSFetchedResultsController` to do that?

Comment: I instantiate Core Data in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of `AppDelegate`. I have no idea of `loadView`. I need read user data and display it in almost every view. So I decide to display it in a container view. I'm not using `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load data then find your child controller in `parrentController.childViewControllers` and send this data to it. Example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadData];
    MyChildViewController childViewController = [self.childViewControllers firstObject];
    [childViewController setData:self.dataForChild];
    [childViewController updateInterface];
}
```

loadData, dataForChild, setData, updateInterface are your custom methods / properties.

Comment: How did it in swift ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a method in your class (the method loads the date from databse) and calls this method inside the method prepareForSegue.
example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     (you method) 
     ....

}
```